# Auto-saving before running a test?

Tags: vim, rspec, automated-tests

I'm fairly new to Vim but this is something I've been wondering about for a while.

Let's say you're using the rspec.vim plugin and you want to run a spec. You have the RunCurrentSpecFile() function mapped to `<Leader>s`.

So if you make a change to your spec, you need 5 keystrokes to re-run it:

```
<Esc>:w<Leader>s
```

But when would you ever want to run the spec *without* saving the file first? So why not map `<Leader>s` so that it saves the file *then* runs the spec. So you save two keystrokes:

```
<Esc><Leader>s
```

I'm not asking about the mechanics of doing this in `.vimrc`, I'm sure it's quite straightforward. I'm questioning why I've never see anyone with Vim configured this way. Is there some downside that I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe because the subset of vim configs you have seen is not representative of the entirety of the configs of rspec.vim users. Or maybe you missed the autosaving command mapped to Esc. Or maybe because Esc is usually not accounted for. Or maybe because it doesn't matter to the people of whom you have seen the config because they use a watcher behind the scene.

Comment: Those are all valid points!

Answer (score 0):

Add `exec "w"` in your funciton **RunCurrentSpecFile()**

This is my **RunResult** function:

```
function! marslofunc#RunResult()
  let mp = &makeprg
  let ef = &errorformat
  let exeFile = expand("%:t")
  exec "w"
  if "python" == &filetype
    setlocal makeprg=python\ -u
  elseif "perl" == &filetype
    setlocal makeprg=perl
  elseif "ruby" == &filetype
    setlocal makeprg=ruby
  elseif "autohotkey" == &filetype
    setlocal makeprg=AutoHotkey
  endif
  set efm=%C\ %.%#,%A\ \ File\ \"%f\"\\,\ line\ %l%.%#,%Z%[%^\ ]%\\@=%m
  silent make %
  copen
  let &makeprg = mp
  let &errorformat = ef
endfunction
```

Details can be checked [here](https://github.com/Marslo/MarsloFunc/blob/master/autoload/marslofunc.vim#L77)

Answer (score 0):

As I know more and more about Vim I also wonder how to speed up my workflow and got same idea as you. I achieved this behavior by adding this line to .vimrc:

```
let g:rspec_command = ":w | !clear && echo rspec {spec} && rspec {spec}"
```

if you use spring for speeding up your tests (which i definitely recommend) use:

```
let g:rspec_command = ":w | !clear && echo bin/rspec {spec} && bin/rspec {spec}"
```